# Finding the dimension of $Alt^2(V)$ and $Sym^2 (V)$, given that $V = \mathbb{C}^2$.

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory

The question is quite clear, I think. I know that if I can count the basis elements, then I am done. Here is the information I was given about these two spaces:

$Sym^2(V) = < a \otimes b + b \otimes a>$ and $Alt^2(V) = <a \otimes b - b \otimes a>$.

I'm not sure where to go from here. We were given the basis in class, but we need to $get$ the basis in order to count it. Any help would be nice :)

Comment: What is the base field? $\mathbb{R, C, Q}$...?

Comment: The base field is $\mathbb{C}$, or at least I would assume. It wasn't given to us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $Sym^2(V) \subset V \otimes V$. A basis of $V \otimes V$ is given by 
$$(e_1 \otimes e_1, e_1 \otimes e_2, e_2 \otimes e_1, e_2 \otimes e_2) = (f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4).$$
We have a linear map $T:V \otimes V \rightarrow V \otimes V$ given on generators by 
$$a \otimes b \rightarrow a \otimes b + b \otimes a$$
(so the image of a sum $a_1 \otimes b_1 + \dots + a_n \otimes b_n$ is just the sum of the images of $a_1 \otimes b_1, \dots, a_n \otimes b_n$). Clearly, the image of $T$ is $Sym^2(V)$. It holds that $T(f_1) = 2 f_1$, and similarly for $T(f_4) = 2f_4$. However, $T(f_2) = f_2 + f_3 = T(f_3).$
It holds that $f_1$, $f_4$ and $f_2 + f_3$ are linearly independent, so the dimension of the image of $T$ is three. A similar thing can be done for $Alt^2(V)$, which will turn out to be one-dimensional.

Interestingly, $Sym^2(V)$ corresponds to the space of symmetric $2 \times 2$-matrices ($A^T = A$) and $Alt^2(V)$ to the space of alternating $2 \times 2$-matrices ($A^T = -A$), which can be shown via a linear isomorphism $V \otimes V \rightarrow Mat(2,\mathbb{C})$.

This can be generalized for $V = \mathbb{C}^n$ and yields a formula in terms of $n$ for the dimensions of $Sym^2(V)$ and $Alt^2(V)$.